# How to provide CI for prediction for mixed model? lsmeans vs predictInterval

Tags: confidence-interval, random-effects-model, prediction-interval, lsmeans

I have a linear mixed model, say:

$$y \approx x_1 + \cdots + x_n + (1\,|\ \text{person})$$

I would like to have a Confidence interval for the prediction, so I would like to say:

if $x_1=3\ $ and $\ x_2=6$, etc, and ignoring the random effect, then $y$ is probably between 10 and 12.

I have found 2 ways to do this:

- with lsmeans
- with predictInterval in merTools.

The 2nd method gives me a much wider CI than the first. My question is: Why is this?

Thank you for your attention.

Toy code example:

```
library(lsmeans)
library(lme4)

# create some data
N <- 100
x <- seq(1,N)
person <- c(rep("a",20),rep("b",20),rep("c",20),rep("d",20),
        rep("e",20))
re <- c(rep(0,20),rep(2,20),rep(5,20),rep(8,20),rep(12,20))


y <- 3 + 2.1* x + re + rnorm(N,1,24)
plot(y~x)

# fit model
n <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|person) )
summary(n)

# first method: lsmeans
#
m.rg1 <- ref.grid(n)
lsmeans(m.rg1,"x")


# second method: predictInterval
#
new.data <- data.frame(x=50, person='c')
pI <- predictInterval(n,newdata=new.data, which='fixed',level=0.95)
pI

# third method: Simulation. This has result similar to predictInterval
#
s <- numeric()
for (i in 1:1000) {
   s[i] <- simulate(n, newdata=new.data)[1]
}
s <- unlist(s)
hist(s)
quantile(s,0.025)
quantile(s,0.975)
```

I do get a warning message with predictInterval, but I do not get that in my real code, and I doubt it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my own question: Lsmeans gives a Confidence Interval, and predictInterval gives a prediction interval. Quite obvious, really.